# Gnuplot - Plot graph with continuously varying line color - plot with color fade / transition

Tags: plot, colors, gnuplot, strange-attractor, lorenz-system

I am using GNU plot (gnuplot) to plot some output data from integration of a strange attractor ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Strange_attractor)) - and as this is a strange attractor the line "rolls around itself in 3D space".

This makes it difficult to see what happens when plotting a lot of data. See this image: [image: Lorenz System]

**Is there any way to plot a transitioning or fading color from say red at the start to blue at the end?**  I know gnuplot is a powerful tool but perhaps I ask too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer here: [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplotting.org/using-a-palette-as-line-color/)

```
# start value for H
h1 = 117/360.0
# end value for H
h2 = 227/360.0
# creating the palette by specifying H,S,V
set palette model HSV functions (1-gray)*(h2-h1)+h1,1,0.68

splot "output.csv" every 100 using 2:3:4:1 with lines linecolor palette title "Lorenz System"
```

The 4th argument after using is the color variable to use. In my case this is the time variable. (Col 1)

[image: This is what it looks like now]